# How to arrange key and value by formula or function in Ms Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, I have 2 cells key and corresponding value like [image: this]

If I change order of elements in key ( Text) That value at next cell is also changed with right order at key cell.
Please help me how to make formula or function to get that. Thank you.

I tried with this formula However It doesn't work for me
[image: Click here 1]

[image: Or click here]

Comment: What version of Excel? 2019 or 2010? Title and tag differ. Also, any attempt from your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ***Excel 2019***, as stated in your title

```
B6: =TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($B$2,"-","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"), N(IF(1,MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A6,"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)))))
```

*A bit simpler in Office 365 and Excel 2021:*

```
B6: =TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($B$2,"-","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),
MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A6,"*","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A$2,"*","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),0)))
```

*and fill down as needed*

[image]

*If your version is truly 2010, I'd suggest a VBA (or Power Query) solution.*

*If you have a MAC, you'll need a different and more complex method to create the array since you won't have the `FILTERXML` function*

***Edit***
*For earlier versions here is a VBA User Defined Function that should work in most any version*
*It makes use of the `ArrayList` object to `Match` the positions from `Key` to `Value`*

```
Option Explicit
Function orderByKey(newKey As String, baseKey As String, baseValue As String) As String
    Dim nk As Object, bk As Object, bv As Object, nv As Object
    Dim v
xToAL nk, newKey, "*"
xToAL bk, baseKey, "*"
xToAL bv, baseValue, "-"

Set nv = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each v In nk
    nv.Add bv.Item(bk.indexof(v, 0))
Next v

orderByKey = Join(nv.toarray, "-")

End Function
'=================================================================
Private Sub xToAL(al As Object, str As String, sdelim As String)
    Dim v, w
    Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    v = Split(str, sdelim)
    For Each w In v
        al.Add CStr(w)
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your formula at B6 cell then It return `0` instead of `0-4`. Could you check again your formula , please?

Comment: @Parabol As you can see from the screenshot, it works with the data you presented. But I cannot see your screen.

Comment: I posted my capture screen, Please find it for your information

Comment: Please see my question I added more photos to show your formula in my case. The result is `0` . Please help. Thank you

Comment: @Parabol You are entering the formula incorrectly. For some reason, you decided to enter the formula as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  Not sure why you did that, but if you confirm the formula normally, by just hitting `enter`, you should get the desired results.

Comment: If I hit `enter` that formula return `#VALUE!` I believe that you can solve it  easily :D

Comment: @Parabol I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  Suggest you upload an xlsx file that reproduces the error to some sharing site (eg dropbox, onedrive, drive) and post a link here.

Comment: Please help, This file with your formula https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjS_lRIyKcboyCsD2q-PYAQsganb?e=iSySc

Comment: @Parabol It may be that the formula won't work in Excel 2019. Try `=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($B$2,"-","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),
N(IF(1,MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A6,"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$2,"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),0)))))`  If that doesn't work, I'd suggest writing a VBA Function for your version of Excel.

Comment: This new formula works for me Thank you

Comment: Ok, I accept your answer Thank you, Also vote my question please